# How to add firebase, Firebase Firestore & Messaging to flutter windows app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, flutter-windows

> I need to add Firebase, Firebase Firestore & Messaging to my flutter
> desktop app.
>
> in my android app it is working well. i need to this to work on
> desktop app.
>
> when I run flutter app on windows, it showing the welcome screen logo,
> stuck on the logo
>
> it is not going to another screen

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/Auth/login_Screen.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/MainScreen.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/WelcomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:graphic_solutions/api/firebase_api.dart';
import 'firebase_config.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

void main() async {
  FirebaseConfig.configure();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Graphsol',
      initialRoute: '/welcome_screen',
      routes: {
        '/welcome_screen': (context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
        '/main_screen': (context) => const MainScreen(),
        '/login_screen': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to

- [firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)
- [firebase messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging),

they are not available for windows however [firebase core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core)
is available for windows

Comment: firebase core 

I used this on the project it is working for web, android,ios
but not for windows